# Laravel mail attachment timeout

Tags: php, email, pdf, laravel-5, email-attachments

I'm using the new Mailing class from Laravel 5.4. 
Normal (Without attachment) sending does work as expected.
But whenever I try to add an PDF attachment it doesn't work:

```
Maximum execution time of 90 seconds exceeded
```

Currently using SMTP for gmail.
But also doesn't work with Amazon SES (also SMTP).

Really stuck with this, as it doesn't give me clear error messages...

Comment: maybe the attachment is taking too long to load and thus exceeding your maximum php execution limit. Now changing the php execution time to a higher value is not the proper solution so I suggest you to implement a  Job( mailSendJob in your case)  and Queue the job so that it will run in background without blocking the UI. see here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It isn't the PDF, as another PDF has the same issue. The Queue also not works (Mail::Queue instead of Mail::send) as it just sends it without PDF... (Which is also really weird).

Comment: Okay so you have the jobs table, but have you configured failed jobs table? If not  check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs, (remember to migrate, restart queue worker and include tries flag when you next run the queue) so after setting up the failed jobs table you can see in the table field if there is any exception being thrown

Comment: Thank you! Will try that

Comment: Any update how to fix that issue?

Answer (score 2):

It worked when I added the "failed_jobs" table.
Apparently Laravel doesn't handle the queue well if you don't have the failed queue table.